# What would be an efficient way to store a word collection using Span<T>?

Tags: c#, memory

I need to store a collection of words in a `Span<T>`. Using a `string[]` is very simple and is efficient. I would like to do the same using `Span<T>`. I can use `Span<byte>` instead of a `string` but I can't use a `Span<Span<byte>>` instead of a `string[]`.

Since using `Span<Span<byte>>` is forbidden by the compiler, one solution would be having a maximum word size and store the words in a `Span<byte>` with size maximum number of words * maximum word size.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
int numberOfWords;
int maxWordSize;
Span<byte> words = stackalloc[numberOfWords * maxWordSize];
Span<int> wordSize = stackalloc[numberOfWords];
```

So instead of:

```
string[] wordArray;
int index;
.....
var someString = wordArray[index];
```

I would use:

```
Span<byte> someWord;
someWord = GetWord(index * maxWordSize, wordSize[index]);
```

So, if a `string[]` can be looked at like an array of char arrays, having two dimensions, my idea was to flatten the structure to one dimension and retrieve each word by index * size instead of retrieving it by index. I am not sure that it is possible to build a two dimensional data structure using `Span<T>`.

However, while this will work, I feel that I waste much memory since I will reserve the same amount of memory for each word and there can be lots of small words.

Is the there a better way to replace a `string[]` with a `Span`, i.e. waste less memory and be as efficient?

Comment: I think you're probably going to need your own `MySpan` struct, with a `startIndex` and `length`. Store these in an array, list or dictionary, and manufacture a `Span<char>` or `Span<byte>` when you need to

Comment: Keeping track of startIndex sounds good. Thank you! I will try this.